# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while using lambda in python2

Tags: python-2.x

I want to print the cube of the numbers in the Fibonacci series and i am using the code  below:

```
def fib_series():
   o = int(raw_input ("enter the number for the Fibonacci series to print : ")) 
   
   
   if o == 1 : return [1]
   if o==0: return []
   lst = [0,1]
      
   for i in range(2,o):
       lst.append(lst[i-1] + lst[i-2])
      return lst  

fib_series()
cube = lambda x : x:x:x 
print (list((map(cube,fib_series))))
```

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: First, did you mean `cube = lambda x : x*x*x`?

Comment: Yes , i meant the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fib_series():
  o = int(raw_input ("enter the number for the Fibonacci series to print : ")) 
  
  
  if o == 1 : return [1]
  if o==0: return []
  lst = [0,1]
    
  for i in range(2,o):
    lst.append(lst[i-1] + lst[i-2])
  return lst  

fib_series()
cube = lambda x : x*x*x # Changed this from x:x:x 
print (list((map(cube,fib_series))))
```

Comment: I tried it but i am getting the below error now:                                                          TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-46089778dffb> in <module>()
     13 fib_series()
     14 cube = lambda x : x*x*x # Changed this from x:x:x
---> 15 print (list((map(cube,fib_series))))

TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
cube = lambda x: x**3